# jump to element with horizontally scrolling

Tags: jquery

I am facing issue in making my website jump to element horizontally.

I have a sidebar which is "fixed" to the left. There are links which allows users to click the content which is to the right of this sidebar, it will jump to the elements.
So the issue is that, if any users click on LINK1, it will jump to that element on the content on the right. But if the user clicks it for second time , the position did not stay. it has jump back to the beginning of the content. I need help in this.

```
$(".main_sidemenu_inpage_link").click(function(){
    var panel_id = $(this).attr('for');
    var sidebarPanel = $("#sidebar_panel").width();
    var numToScroll = $('#container_'+panel_id+"_content_panel").offset().left;
    $('#overview_panel').animate({ scrollLeft: numToScroll}, 900,function(){});
});
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a fiddle? This is gibberish .

Comment: Please show us your basic HTML as well.